# calculator delete same text from textbox asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am making a calculator in asp.net empty web site adding a web form into it..

my problem is i am stuck at one point where i want that if the user inputs `+-*/` 2 times as `50+-` then this extra `-` should be deleted from the textbox or if the user input `50**` then `*` should be deleted from the textbox.

so i wrote this code..but its not working..nothing is happening

```
String s = ResultBox.Text.ToString();
        if (s[s.Length - 2].ToString().Equals(s[s.Length - 1].ToString()))
            ResultBox.Text.Remove(s.Length - 1);
        else
            ResultBox.Text.Remove(ResultBox.Text.Length - 2, 1);
```

and sorry for the title of this page..i don't know what to write the title of this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var input = ResultBox.Text;
var operators = new[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
if (operators.Any (o => o == input[input.Length - 1]) 
    && operators.Any (o => o == input[input.Length - 2]))
{
    input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
}

ResultBox.Text = input;
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.Remove` does not change the original string - it returns a new string.

```
String s = ResultBox.Text.ToString();
if (s[s.Length - 2].ToString().Equals(s[s.Length - 1].ToString()))
  ResultBox.Text = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
else
  ResultBox.Text = s.Remove(ResultBox.Text.Length - 2, 1);
```